# parse 1 dimentional JSON Array into an ordinary array

Tags: java, json, parsing, getjson

i have String from php, let say

```
stringName={instruction:["1","2","3"]}
```

and i want to turn tat string into an array
i have try this

```
stringName= stringName={instruction:["1","2","3"]}
JSONArray menuitemArray = null;

    String[] result= null;
    try
    {
        jObject = new JSONObject(stringName);
        menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("instruction");

        for (int i=0; i<menuitemArray.length(); i++) 
        {
            result[i] = menuitemArray.getJSONArray(i).toString();
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it give me error :(

anyone know the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*menuitemArray* is an array so use `getString(index)` method to read an element,

```
str=menuitemArray.getString(i);
```

And you can't use `result` array because it is not *initialized*. Use `List<String>` instead of array.